# Is Yum (and YumEx) intended for use on Debian/Ubuntu systems, as well as CentOS systems?

Tags: linux, debian, yum

I have been building C++ server applications for Linux, typically in a CentOS environment within a virtual machine.  A while ago, when setting up my development environment in CentOS, I became accustomed to using Yum (with YumEx) to manage installed libraries on the CentOS system.

I am now building the application on a Debian system.

Is Yum (and YumEx) intended for use with Debian/Ubuntu, as well as CentOS?  If not, what analogous package manager should I use with Debian/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified) was built to deal with [RPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) packages, as they are used e.g. with Redhat/CentOS or SuSE Linux. On Debian and its derivates (so also on Ubuntu), RPM is not the packaging system of the choice. The equivalent to Yum would be [APT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) (as the equivalent to the `rpm` command would be [dpkg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg)). You might want to look up the linked references for details. Here for a short answer: Ubuntu uses a different packaging system for its software, so Yum is not a good choice to maintain an Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PackageKit, which is present on both distributions:
  http://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/pk-using.html

If you have minimal OS, you can install them

```
  yum install PackageKit
```

on CentOS or:

```
  apt-get install packagekit
```

on Debian.